# How to show a loading screen in react or a conditionally rendered layout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loading

I'm being really thick for a moment and cant work out this simple thing

I basically want to show a loading screen when my app is not ready. but if the app is ready, I want to show either a login button OR the users home screen

```
useEffect(() => {
        setLoaded(true)
}, [])
return loaded ? (
    <div>
        {user.isLoggedIn ? (
            <>
                <div> welcome {user} </div>
            </>
        ) : (
            <SignInButton onClick={login}>
                <img src={'/images/google.png'} /> Sign in with Google
            </SignInButton>
        )}
    </div>
) : (
    <LoadingContainer>
        <img src="/images/loading.gif" width="30" style={{ margin: 'auto' }} />
    </LoadingContainer>
)
```

it's flickering now where it finishes loading, then shows the google screen and then flicks to the home screen. I guess because im setting loading to false BEFORE the user is ready. how can I fix this so it's seamless?

I also tried this

```
useEffect(() => {
      if(user){
        setLoaded(true)
   }
}, [])
```

but obviously that is stupid as when im not logged in, it will show loading forever. please someone help solve my afternoon pain

Comment: What determines whether the user is logged in? You could create a loading state for when the user authentication starts, and keep the loading screen while it's authenticating..

Comment: it gets determined in the redux state. I have `user.isLoggedIn` listening to firebase auth

Comment: I'm guessing that you're dispatching some sort of action to authenticate with firebase. When you do that you could set a boolean on the user like user.isAuthenticating, and set it to true when the action is dispatched, and set it to false the authentication is done.

Comment: ok I fixed it. I decided to "life the state up" into my parent component where I set the user. now im just setting loading after I've set user. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try using the setTimeout method, say for example show the loader for 3 seconds like

```
useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(setLoaded(true), 3000);
}, [])
```